# GNU plot on non uniform data in x axis with fix interval

Tags: gnuplot

```
9                              1782.091513,
24                             4731.999530,
36                             6377.046661,
80                             9377.983901,
108                            9158.024005,
210                            4314.926970,
540                            56799.564,
2000                           67908.2343,
7000                           45345.657,    
12000                          34234.3624,
```

Plotting this giving me a graph on which i am not able to see the small values. I want to fix the interval b/w each value of x axis. So that graph will be visible on full table.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your axes to be logarithmic:

```
set logscale x
set logscale y
```

Answer (score 0):

Logscale is probably what you actually want here as pointed out by choroba.  A second (less standard) way to plot this is to use the values in the first column as the `xticlabels`.

```
plot 'yourdatafile' u 2:xticlabels(1)
```

This will result in a plot where the values are equally spaced on the x-axis, labelled with the corresponding x positions from the datafile.